# Change iframe source from HTTP to HTTPS with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe, https

I have a plugin on my WordPress site that automatically adds an iframe to each of my product pages. I have recently started using CloudFlare's Flexible SSL and now that iframe URL won't load because it's considered insecure. Is there any way that I could dynamically change the iframe's URL to be https instead of http?

I have already confirmed that both versions of the URL work the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will search and replace `http` for `https` on all the `iframes` on page.

need any further help putting it in let me know;

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rxhs63d/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#pros_reviews iframe").each(function() {
    var $frame = $(this)
    $frame.attr('src', $frame.attr('src').replace('http:', 'https:'))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pros_reviews">
  <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Do I need a specific version of jQuery for this to work? As of now, I have version 1.11.3 being loaded.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but it's not working.

https://apocalypse.supplies/store/books-dvds/books/survival-hacks-over-200-ways-to-use-everyday-items-for-wilderness-survival/

Comment: Silly me you need no conflict for WordPress check my updated code

Comment: I'm getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Also, the content is not loading in the correct tabs now but maybe that's because of the error.

Comment: can you point me in the direction of the iframe whats the name of the plugin you are using

Comment: The iframe URL is: http://www.amazon.com/reviews/iframe?akid=AKIAIG3NRUQLRGJ4PHJA&alinkCode=sp1&asin=1440593345&atag=bm0da-20&exp=2022-03-24T13%3A48%3A04Z&v=2&sig=O8tBdwe%2FB2meABoRrHDaIAjMBUjhOd5bI7N3tTG%2Fs6M%3D but it's different for every product and the plugin is called Prosociate http://www.prosociate.com/

Comment: Something else I thought about was going directly to the database and editing all the iframe sources.

Comment: yeah you could go right in and edit the db but would that help with future edits? I have updated the code to target the pros_reviews see if that stops the error. might be happening because there is a few iframes on page.

Comment: Also try putting the snippet under the wp_foot instead of above it. Theres just so much loading chances are there is a clash somewhere

Comment: The new code works and the user can see the reviews now. However, the browser is still seeing it as insecure and there's an exclamation point on the lock icon (firefox). I don't want to have to do it, but it might be best for me to change all the iframe sources within the database. I really appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 0):

To load the iframe with the same protocol (http or https) use a relative scheme : '//example.com' instead of 'http://example.com'. '//' indicate to use the same scheme as the parent page

Note that **it is not secure**. a most secure way will be to always load 'https://' (and set up a 301 redirect for all pages from http to https)

Comment: I think the issue is his plugin forces the http. He has no control over what is printed otherwise he would just put https

Comment: @DCdaz I was not sure if by *dynamically* he means "use the same protocol than the parent" (my answer) or "I can't touch the source, can JS fix it?" (your anwser)

Comment: minute someone says WordPress it's pretty safe to assume they cant edit the printed content lol

Comment: I have no control on the iframe URL that is being loaded.